# MySQL Select by index

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select values from the MySQL database by a range of the index?

For example I have the search values of A-Be

How can I retrieve values that start with "A" ranging to "Be"

I've tried using LIKE/RLIKE but I'm only able to get the values I set and not everything in between.

```
$query = $db->query( "SELECT place FROM places WHERE place RLIKE '^$i[0]' AND place RLIKE '^$i[1]'" );
```

I'm guessing that BETWEEN would need to be used but I'm not sure where to put it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try with **REGEXP** like

```
$query = $db->query( "SELECT place FROM places WHERE place REGEXP '^$i[0]'
                      OR place REGEXP '^$i[1]'" );
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed a part in the query. I've updated my question.